# Android: ContextMenu but not taking up the whole window

Tags: android

I was searching for a way to create a pop up when i long click an `ImageView`, and i've seen many answers of `ContextMenu` but what i saw from `ContextMenu` is that it takes the whole window, is there a way to achieve something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxWel.png)? a small list of options?

[image]

Comment: pop up menu http://developer.android.com/images/ui/popupmenu.png ?

Answer (score 0):

read on Android [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) or [dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), you can create your own layout and remove the backdrop. 
You can also look at other open source projects like this one: [Tooltips](https://github.com/rharter/android-tooltips)

Comment: it is more like super tooltips but i cant seem to inport it in android studio

Comment: super tooltips is discontinued, no support, use at your own risk. Just add this to your gradle file:     compile 'com.nhaarman.supertooltips:library:3.0.+'

Comment: yes, i will instead use popup menu, thanks for the help!